# Slot machine probabilities?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Probability of net gain given 100 pulls of slot machine with 3 slots, each numbered 1 through 9, and 1 dollar per push with average winning for any given winning push equal to 2 dollars (happening when there are either 2 of the same number, or 3 of the same number)?

First I considered the probability of getting either 2 of the same number, or 3 of the same number. I came up with P(two 8s) = (3C2)(1/9)^2(8/9) = 24/729. And, P(three 8s) = (3C3)(1/9)^3 = 1/729. So, P(two 8s, or three 8s) = 25/729 = 3.4%

Then considering 100 pulls of the slot machine, I got (100 C 50)(3.4%)^50(96.6%)^50 which came up to be a very small number, which I do not think is right. I considered winning 50 times with 2 dollars means you gained 100 dollars, and put in 100 dollars. So this probability, I think, represents the probability of breaking even. Is this correct? If so, how to compute probability of a net gain?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your probability of getting $2$ or $3$ $8$s is correct but, you can win for any other number than $8$ too, so you need to take the union of those. Luckily the event are disjoints so in the end it is just $9\times \frac{25}{729}=\frac{25}{81}$. The probability of breaking even is then as you mentioned ${100 \choose 50} \left(\frac{25}{81}\right)^{50} \left( \frac{56}{81} \right)^{50}$ which is of course pretty small because we consider a very large space of events. Something more interesting would be to compute (or estimate) the average gain (loss), the probability of wining. Here is the [probability of not loosing](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bi%3D50%7D%5E%7B100%7D%20%7B100%20%5Cchoose%20i%7D%20%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B25%7D%7B81%7D%5Cright)%5E%7Bi%7D%20%5Cleft(%20%5Cfrac%7B56%7D%7B81%7D%20%5Cright)%5E%7B100-i%7D) on wolfram, pretty small. And the [average gain](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bi%3D0%7D%5E%7B100%7D+%7B100+%5Cchoose+i%7D+(2+i-100)+%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B25%7D%7B81%7D%5Cright)%5E%7Bi%7D+%5Cleft(+%5Cfrac%7B56%7D%7B81%7D+%5Cright)%5E%7B100-i%7D) is about $-38.3$. Conclusion : don't play.

Comment: With a prize of 2 dollars, I don't expect that anyone would play, not even those that cannot calculate the expected "gain".

Comment: Well, I wouldn't play as long as I don't make the rules myself

Comment: Can you help me understand the average gain? What does the (i-50) accomplish? A bit confused. Thx!!

Comment: Well, I'm sorry I mess it up, just edited my post, so the gain would be $2 i-100$ and the average loss is around 38